# Express app body parser doesnt work with certain api.s

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twilio

SO i have an express app that I have been building an app that uses a body parser that works with my entire app client side. ( receive post req data )

but `app.use(bodyParser.json());` seemed to cause issues with apis which is why i commented it out. now that I dont use it, i cant receive post data from my website.. What should I do so that apis and my website works?

```
// APP
var app = express();
//app.use(bodyParser.json()); //ISSUE: this is breaks API post //but i need it to recieve MY post req data

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(fileUpload());


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: I just tried an express app with both json and urlencoded body parsers enabled and it worked. Can you post the error you get when Twilio fails with the json parser enabled?

Comment: i just got it, i moved it past all my twilio code and that did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple kludge would be to define the routes that twilio uses before you activate the bodyParser middleware. Without knowing more about why exactly the bodyparser prevents twilio from working, that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

In generell I alway suggest to not register body parsers *globally* for all follow up routes, but directly with the route or only locally for one router (path prefix) where it is required.

Moving the routers of twilio before registering the bodyParser for all following routes will also work, but it is less maintainable.

So if you need `json` data in on specific route, then write it that way:

```
app.post('/some/route', bodyParser.json(), (req, res, next) => {
   // processing of your json
});
```

The reason why I suggest this is, because the body that is submitted to the server is provided as stream. Whenever you register a middleware that will process the body then it will consume the whole content, and you cannot use any other middleware that will also process the body after that. Using it only for the route where you need this parser eliminates this problem, and allows you to use different body parsers depending on the route.

The larger your project becomes the more likely it is that you come to a situation where you need an other body parsers, then you will be most likely at a point where moving the routes would not work anymore.